# Is there any way to send a media file as part of a request in Spring Boot?

Tags: request, multipartform-data

I am new in programming and seeking for a solution to my problem. Here, I am going to describe my problem in as much clarity as I can. 
So, I am working on a problem where I have to create an API which is going to accept (String1, String2, Mediafile(mp3), Mediafile(txt)) and then I have to upload these files somewhere else. 
Here, I want to know do we expect Media Files in the byte[] format or is there any way that I can get that Mediafile as it is(Not in Byte format).

```
package com.self.projects;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.boot.json.JsonParseException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@RestController

@RequestMapping("/hellomedia")

public class TestMediafile {

@RequestMapping(value = "addDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public StudentClassReport addProduct(
        @RequestParam String studentReportJson, 
        @RequestParam MultipartFile report, 
        @RequestParam MultipartFile transcription,
        @RequestParam int marks) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
 studentClassReport studentReport  = new objectMapper().readValue(studentReportJson, StudentClassReport.class);
 byte[] myReport = report.getBytes();
 byte[] myTranscription = transcription.getBytes();
 studentReport.setTranscription(myTranscription);
 studentReport.setReport(myReport); 
 return studentReport; 
}
```

}